# Fastet way to shuffle a dataframe to calculate P value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shuffle, p-value

I have the following data frame (actual length of dataframe is much larger) :

```
spend_df:

var   spend
 1     120
 2     200
 1     111
 1     143
 1     230
 2     180
 2     190
 2     94
 2     100
 1     278
```

here ´var´ column tell which group of the test row belongs, i need to shuffle the df 1000 times to assign each rows randomly to different sides of test randomly then groupby 'var' and calculate the difference fro every iteration. At  the end calculate how many time the difference between groups sum was larger that actual difference:

i take the following approach:

```
def simulate(df):
    simul_df = df.copy()

    shuffled_var = simul_df.sample(frac=1)
    shuffled_var.index = simul_df.index # replace shuffled series' index with the real one

    simul_df['var'] = shuffled_var
    simul_grouped = simul_df.groupby('var').sum()['spend']
    simul_difference = simul_grouped.iloc[1] - simul_grouped.iloc[0]
    return simul_difference


simulate(spend_df)
```

and this is how i calculate how many times simulated difference was larger that actual difference:

```
simulations = np.array([simulate(spend_df) for i in range(1000)])
(simulations > real_difference).mean()
```

here real_difference is the difference between sums of two groups spend(group by 'var'):

```
grouped=df.groupby('var').sum().reset_index()
real_diff=grouped.iloc[1] - grouped.iloc[0]
```

in this case it is : 882-764= 118

whenever i shuffle the dataframe i need to calculate the difference for new groups like above then i need to find out how many times this simulated differences where more than real_diff

This solution seems a bit hacky to me is there any faster or more organized way to this simulation task for calculating P value? without going deep to statistical methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***attempt 1***

```
def gdif(df):
    v, s = df.values.T
    return np.diff(df.groupby('var').spend.sum().values)[0]

def shuf(df):
    np.random.shuffle(df['var'].values)
    return df

def sim1(df):
    sdf = df.copy()

    real_diff = gdif(sdf)

    return (np.array([gdif(shuf(sdf)) for _ in range(1000)]) > real_diff).mean()

sim1(spend_df)

0.52900000000000003
```

***attempt 2***
*with more `numpy`*

```
def gdif2(values):
    v, s = values.T
    r = np.arange(v.size)

    a = v.argsort()
    c = s[a].cumsum()
    d0 = c[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(v[a]))[0]]
    return c[-1] - 2 * d0

def shuf2(v):
    np.random.shuffle(v[:, 0])
    return v

def sim2(df):
    values = df.values

    real_diff = gdif2(values)

    return (np.array([gdif2(shuf2(values)) for _ in range(1000)]) > real_diff).mean()

sim2(spend_df)

0.52700000000000002
```

---

***naive time tetsting***

[image]

Comment: Thank you , i wonder how it calculates real difference. what i mean by readl difference is groupby('var').sum() so that we have some of spend for two groups var1 and var2 then subtracting them. is your function do the same?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question with a calculation of what `real_difference` is for your sample `spend_df`

Comment: Actually attempt one calculates real difference in way i want, but attempt 2 not